# How to get single result after grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
TYPE      AMOUNT  

purc    100
sale    120
sale    80
purc    150
sale    50
sale    70
sale    120
purc    60
```

when i run this query "select type, sum(AMOUNT) as amount from MyTable GROUP by type"
i can get 2 result set like

```
TYPE     AMOUNT
purc    310
sale    440
```

But i want single result in one query only for sale and purc like

```
SALE   PURC   PROFIT
440    310    130
```

What is that single query?

Comment: I found solution. 
This query is working for my expectation
select t1.SALE, t2.PURC from
(select sum(AMOUNT) as SALE from test3 where "TYPE" = 'sale') as t1,
(select sum(AMOUNT) as PURC from test3 where "TYPE" = 'purc') as t2

Comment: That's ok if you have only a few rows, if you have many I think my query would be faster.

Comment: why do you want something like that?

Comment: I am using BIRT engine Report. i need 2 aggregate sum value in single result in 1 query. first should be sale 2nd should be purc

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Comment: Result Query: "select t1.SALE, t2.PURC, (t1.SALE - t2.PURC) as PROFIT from
(select sum(AMOUNT) as SALE from MyTable where "TYPE" = 'sale') as t1,
(select sum(AMOUNT) as PURC from MyTable where "TYPE" = 'purc') as t2"
Profit added in same single result

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(`TYPE` = 'purc', `AMOUNT`, 0)) as `PURC`,
  SUM(IF(`TYPE` = 'sale', `AMOUNT`, 0)) as `SALE`
FROM `MyTable`
```

This should perform a so-called **pivoting** on your table.

Using `CASE` instead of `IF`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE `TYPE` WHEN 'purc' THEN `AMOUNT` ELSE 0 END) as `PURC`,
  SUM(CASE `TYPE` WHEN 'sale' THEN `AMOUNT` ELSE 0 END) as `SALE`
FROM `MyTable`
```

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42Y03: 'IF' is not recognized as a function or procedure.

In derby CASE is used instead of IF

Comment: I never used Derby, so I didn't now, but that is valid SQL for mysql, as your tag says.

Comment: The query is now correct =) It was just missing an `END` to the `CASE` statement

Comment: Syntax error: Encountered "TYPE" at line 2, column 12.
if i remove Type from query, 
1 more error-> : A conditional has a non-Boolean operand. The operand of a conditional must evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.

Comment: Perhaps you just have to properly escape the fields, I'll update my query.