# How to generate this SQL query like pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I want to three table union to one query like a pivot table. 
My main table name is products and two support tables name are code_keys and code_values

I have a main table name:  **products**

```
+------------------+ 
| Field            |
+------------------+     
| productid        |     
| catpath          |  
| da               |
| l0               |
| ig               |
| des              |
| notes            |
| wire             |
| lmm              |
+------------------+
```

example data:

```
+-----------+------+------+------+
| productid | da   | ig   | des  |
+-----------+------+------+------+
|         5 | 78   | 33   | 23   |
|         8 | 88   | 13   | 21   |
+-----------+------+------+------+
```

and 2 conf table names: **code_keys**. Store code structure.

```
+--------+
| Field  |
+--------+
| codeid |
| title  |
| codekey|
| format |
+--------+
```

example data:

```
+--------+----------------+
| codeid | title          |
+--------+----------------+
|      2 | St Code        |
|      3 | Rear Les       |
+--------+----------------+
```

**code_values**

```
+-------+
| Field |
+-------+
| id    |
| pid   | -> Product ID
| codeid| 
| value |
+-------+
```

and finally example data:

```
+----+------+--------+--------------+
| id | pid  | codeid | value        |
+----+------+--------+--------------+
|  9 |    5 |      2 | ST 102 200 R |
| 10 |    5 |      3 | 12 000 33    |
| 11 |    6 |      2 | ST 343 432 R |
| 12 |    6 |      3 | 34 343 24    |
| 15 |    8 |      2 | ST 100 101 R |
| 16 |    8 |      3 | 11 223 34    |
| 17 |    0 |      2 | ST 343 432 R |
| 18 |    0 |      3 | 34 343 24    |
+----+------+--------+--------------+
```

***I want to show like this into one query:***

**Product Columns | *code_keys rows > columns* |**

```
+-----------+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
| productid | da   | ig   | des  | St Code      | Rear Les |
+-----------+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
|         5 | 78   | 33   | 23   | ST 102 200 R | 12 000 33| 
|         8 | 88   | 13   | 21   | ST 100 101 R | 11 223 34| 
+-----------+------+------+------+--------------+----------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the way you have asked. But also show some of your efforts what you have tried.

Comment: Search SO for "mysql pivot table". This is a common question.

Comment: Pivot table conversion answer is available in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299195/mysql-select-column-name-as-field

Comment: My code_keys data is dynamically. User can add more code. And searchable.

Comment: try out this url [Stack Overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587944/how-to-get-single-result-after-grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.da, p.ig, p.des
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ck.title = 'St Code' 
                         THEN cv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'St Code'
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN ck.title = 'Rear Les' 
                         THEN cv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Rear Les'
FROM Products p
JOIN code_values cv ON p.productid = cv.pid
JOIN code_keys ck ON cv.codeid = ck.codeid
GROUP BY p.productid;
```

If you have unknown number of `code_keys` you can try this dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `title` = ''',
      `title`,
      ''' THEN cv.value ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      `title`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM code_keys ck JOIN code_values cv ON cv.codeid = ck.codeid;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.productid, p.da, p.ig, p.des, ', @sql,'
                     FROM Products p
                     JOIN code_values cv ON p.productid = cv.pid
                     JOIN code_keys ck ON cv.codeid = ck.codeid
                    GROUP BY p.productid
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| PRODUCTID | DA | IG | DES |      ST CODE |  REAR LES |
--------------------------------------------------------
|         5 | 78 | 33 |  23 | ST 102 200 R | 12 000 33 |
|         8 | 88 | 13 |  21 | ST 100 101 R | 11 223 34 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6d68/10)

Comment: Thank you again @hims056! work for me :) sorry but how to searchable this keys? for example `ST CODE` LIKE '%102%'

Comment: @maverabilisim - Glad to help you. I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: Can I search into `ST CODE` or `REAR LES` WHERE statment?

Comment: @maverabilisim - Yes. Using sub query [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6d68/11)

Comment: I get an error. "Unknown column 'REAR LES' in 'where clause'". Can you give me an example for sub query?

Comment: @maverabilisim - See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6d68/20) for both static and dynamic query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33532/discussion-between-maverabilisim-and-hims056)